# Can't Compile SSIS Component; Missing Assembly in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2008, ssis

There is no standard control flow task in SSIS to download a file over HTTP. I have tried some workarounds ([Execute Process wget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6650028/how-to-fix-ssis-file-process-not-in-path-warning/6660410#6660410), [Script Task HttpClientConnection](http://www.sqlis.com/post/Downloading-a-file-over-HTTP-the-SSIS-way.aspx)), but have come to the conclusion that thew most robust and reusable way to perform this task is to create a custom component.

I have tried to do this by following [Ray Gorski's guide](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/miscctrl/SQLServer_2005_SSIS.aspx), but have run into problem in my development environment.

The problem is that Visual Studio 2008 does not recognise the `Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts` namespace. It complains with the error message "The type or namespace name 'Dts' does not exist in namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)".

I found advice on [the MSDN forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/1b3ed694-cf02-445e-8ff4-0de4fd45a464/) that says you can add a reference by adding the assembly `ManagedDTS.dll` found in  `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SDK\Assemblies\`, but this directory does not exist on my system. I think this is because I am using SQL Server 2008 and not SQL Server 2005.

How do I fix this problem?

Here is my code, which is based on the sample in Ray Gorski's guide. There is no code here to actually accomplish my task, just an empty stub, which doesn't compile.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Design;

namespace HTTPControlTask
{
    [DtsTask(
        Description = "HTTP",
        DisplayName = "HTTP",
        TaskContact = "Iain Elder",
        TaskType = "SSIS Help Task",
        RequiredProductLevel = DTSProductLevel.None)]
    public class HTTPControlTask : Task, IDTSComponentPersist
    {
    }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of the errors I see when I try to compile it:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the link, Siva. For now using `HTTPClientConnection` is fine, because the two packages I am designing download all their data from just one file. But there are some other packages that have to make multiple HTTP requests to extract all their data, so I will consider using `WebClient` for this task.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On `64-bit` Operating System, you can find the file `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll` in the following path:

**`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`**

On `32-bit` Operating System, you can find the file `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll` in the following path:

**`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\100\SDK\Assemblies`**

The folder **90** under Microsoft SQL Server represents `SQL Server 2005`.

The folder **100** under Microsoft SQL Server represents `SQL Server 2008`.

Comment: Thanks, Siva. I am running a 64-bit operating system and 64-bit version of SQL Server 2008.

Comment: I know this is a long time closed but if you look in those paths and the library isn't there, fire up the SQL Server installation disk and install the SDK. We ran into that today.

Comment: Reinstalling the client tools SDK via the installation disk worked for me.

Comment: The full name is 'Client Tools SDK', which is under: Installation -> New installation or Add Features -> ... -> Feature Selection -> Client Tools SDK

Answer (score 3):

Just a small update on the earlier answer for SQL2012

DLL files are in 110.

Now even after adding the reference you will get the same error if you build your project with .Net3.5 or older profiles.

for SQL2012 you must use .Net4.0 or later else Visual Studio will show you the same error.

Answer (score 1):

After install SS2012, script is ssis packages developed in ss2008r2 have the error described. After several tentatives trying to resolve, i have install the ss2008r2 sdk, open all the scripts and close, and everything is ok now.

Thanks Mark