# SSIS Package calling from Windows service on Windows server R2 : Error -Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsComException:

Tags: c#, ssis, windows-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I am able to execute some SSIS packages from my local computer however when I am trying to execute the same through windows service on Windows server R2 it fails.
Windows Service Code:

using DTS = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime;

```
    DTS.Package pkg;
            DTS.Application app;
            DTS.DTSExecResult pkgResults;
            app = new DTS.Application();
            pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
            pkgResults = pkg.Execute();
```

I am installing the service on the server and when started it fails on app = new DTS.Application();

On the server I have already SSIS installed and I am also able to execute the Package from command prompt.
The complete error message is :

> Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DtsComException:
>
> An Integration Services class cannot be found. Make sure that
>   Integration Services is correctly installed on the computer that is
>   running the application. Also, make sure that the 64-bit version of
>   Integration Services is installed if you are running a 64-bit
>   application.       --->
>
> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Retrieving the COM class
>   factory for component with CLSID
>   {BA785E28-3D7B-47AE-A4F9-4784F61B598A} failed due to the following
>   error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).
>
> at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application..ctor()    --- End
>   of inner exception stack trace ---    at
>   Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.Application..ctor()

Any help on this?

Comment: The error says make sure the 64-bit version is installed, so did you install it or only installed the 32-bit version?

Comment: pls see my comments below for this.

Answer (score 0):

It seem that you have installed the 32-bit version of SSIS, according to this article [64 bit Considerations for Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) if you run it from command prompt the 32-bit version will be used even if the 64-bit version is installed

> By default, a 64-bit computer that has both the 64-bit and 32-bit
>   versions of an Integration Services command prompt utility installed
>   will run the 32-bit version at the command prompt. The 32-bit version
>   runs because the directory path for the 32-bit version appears in the
>   PATH environment variable before the directory path for the 64-bit
>   version. (Typically, the 32-bit directory path is :\Program
>   Files(x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn, while the 64-bit
>   directory path is :\Program Files\Microsoft SQL
>   Server\100\DTS\Binn.)

Now i believe that your service is built against 64-bit, which made the SSIS package request the 64-bit version and it didn't find it.

So you either change it to run as 32-bit or install the 64-bit version of Integration Services.

Comment: On my dev box both 32 & 64 bit version is installed and i made changes to Path environment variable to point to respective Microsoft SQL Server\100\DTS\Binn directory but still no luck. One thing I have found that on the server Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll does not exist and I had copied this dll to service BIN directory. do you see any issue associated with that ?

Comment: so both 32 and 64 bit versions are installed on the Windows server R2 machine? as for the Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedSTS.dll here is the correct location for it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679721/cant-compile-ssis-component-missing-assembly-in-visual-stduio-2008 for 2008 R2 its C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies for 32 and C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\SDK\Assemblies for 64

Comment: Thanks. this dll is not available at suggested path so should I fire up the SQL Server installation disk and install the SDK again or merely copying the libraries will sort out the problem? can u suggest the name of the component to be selected at the time of installation ?

Comment: check [Install Integration Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx) >Select Integration Services to install the Integration Services service and to run packages outside the design environment.

For a complete installation of Integration Services, together with the tools and documentation for developing and managing packages, select both Integration Services and the following Shared Features:

    **Client Tools SDK** to install managed assemblies for Integration Services programming.