# Different errors occurring on start up - SSIS visual studio

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, ssis

I am currently making an SSIS (azure-enabled) package to transfer data between databases, and each time I load the package one of two errors occur. I have no idea of the cause, it is either in my scripts I get the error `The type or namespace name 'Dts' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.SqlServer' (are you missing an assembly reference?)`. Or it compiles fine but the package is unable to execute, and when forced it fails by not being able to run the scripts.

To note, @@version of the SQL server `Microsoft SQL Azure (RTM) - 12.0.2000.8   Jul  3 2019 10:02:53   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation`

And the SSIS is for SQL server 2017, I believe this is the cause of the error since I don't have the file `Microsoft.SQLServer.ManagedDTS.dll` anywhere in the SQL server directory

Comment: Some kind of duplicate? This is for VS 2008 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6679721/cant-compile-ssis-component-missing-assembly-in-visual-studio-2008

Comment: could you please share the script ?

Comment: It's not the code, because if I copy and paste into another package it compiles fine. I am just connecting to a SQL server.

Comment: It's not a duplicate because there is no assembly directory in SQL server 150 folder

Comment: Take a look at https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/c333d8e5-a4ca-470e-a2d8-4f67a5e05a10/missing-microsoftsqlservermanageddts?forum=sqlintegrationservices. There were a couple solutions that look promising, including reinstalling the SQL SDK, or grabbing a copy of the .dll out of the GAC.